# Kanji for Hirohito

Tags: meaning, radicals

I cannot find the kanji for hito, as in the name Hirohito, in my Modern Reader's Japanese-English Character Dictionary (Andrew Nelson). When I searched online I found that the hito was shown as a four stroke kanji, written as nimben and two horizontal strokes similar to the number two. I searched with the nimben and rod radicals with no success. Can someone help me out here?

Comment: Jim Breen's KANJIDIC (accessible through interfaces such as jisho.org) gives indices into various kanji dictionaries, including the original Nelson.  In this case, you could use [the jisho.org kanji search](http://jisho.org/kanji/radicals/), and click on 亻 and 二 to find the character.  The [resulting page](http://jisho.org/kanji/details/%E4%BB%81) lists it under *Classic Nelson*, and says 349.

Comment: What exactly are you asking...?  Are you asking if the one you found (`仁`) is correct, or if it is the correct one of many choices?  I feel that this is too localized anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There is 仁, which fits all of your descriptions. You wouldn't have found it with the rod radical, because the rod is a vertical line. Most digital dictionaries have a search function by stroke number as well (or at least order the results by stroke number), which would have helped. Plus [二]{に} is actually a traditional radical.

My dictionary gives at least the following combinations for Hirohito

> 郭人, 寛人, 寛仁, 宏人, 宏仁, 宏斉, 広人, 広仁, 弘人, 弘仁, 浩人, 浩仁, 祥仁, 仁人, 大仁, 博人, 博仁, 祐人, 裕人, 裕仁, 洋人, 煕人, 洋仁, 皓人